# Can you create a rule in Outlook to forward emails to someone not in CC or To field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to forward a mail to an address whenever I receive a mail without that address in `CC` or `To` field. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called **redirect**. Unfortunately this feature is available for MS Exchange Server accounts only.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is your trigger for the rule.  The Outlook client rules don't really have that level of function.  You could set this up for example to occur if YOU specifically are not in the TO field... but that's about as close as it gets.  If you could change your trigger to something like a specific subject line or something like that, what you want could be managed without much problem.